# Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I tried to run the command 'Enable-Migrations' in a new project and I got the message:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verif
y that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Enable-Migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But in all other projects the command runs just fine.

Why is this happening?

BTW, I'm using VS2010 Professional SP1

**EDIT:** I reinstalled with the commmand: **Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease**
and the problem went away.

Comment: Hi, please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted (which you can do 2 days later), so it won't show up as unanswered question.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. But none of the things in this thread seems to work. Did you reinstall the entire visual studio or did you simply run that command?

Comment: I simply ran the command...

Comment: Sadly, the results of that command for me are just "'EntityFramework 6.1.0' already installed." and it still doesn't have add-migration or enable-migrations as valid commands.

Comment: I am getting Install-Package : Unable to find package 'EntityFramework'. when i try your solution

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I reinstalled with the commmand: `Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease` and the problem went away.

Comment: I built my solution and then closed and reopened VS 2013 and it worked

Comment: Note that `EntityFramework` only supports .net framework 4.0 and 4.5. So, if you are using .net framework 4.6 or higher, it doesn't work.

Comment: @TânNguyễn - what's that? my EntityFramework 6.1.3 NuGet is working fine in my 4.6.x project

Comment: Restart didn't do it for me, but this did.

Answer (score 86):

Just simply re-starting Visual Studio worked for me. 
No need to install packages, etc.

Comment: Restarting VS also worked for me, glad I tried this before trying to reinstal the EntityFramework

Comment: Restarting worked for Visual Studio 2015. No need to install packages.

Comment: A note - I have this issue every time I have to install my packages (like a fresh repo pull). Looks like VS needs to restart before the PM is initialized properly with the new packages (VS Community 2015 Update 1)

Comment: Fresh repo pull also caused this for me. Restart fixed it. (VS Enterprise 2015 Update 2).

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue with VS 2019 Preview, .Net Core, and EntityFramework Core.

Turns out I had to install via NuGet `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`. Once that was done, it worked like a charm.

Comment: +1 - I also needed to restart VS - I think the PM / PS environment needs to be reinitialized after this change

Comment: Adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools did the trick for me with Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 34):

This issue is occurring because we don't have Entity Framework installed.
Please install Entity Framework using the below command.

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
```

Once installed, choose the project in the package manger console default project drop down.

Make sure at least one class in your project inherits from data context, otherwise use the below class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext()
        {
        }
    }
```

If we don't do this we will get another error:

*`No context type was found in the assembly`*

After completing these things you can run

```
enable-migrations
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me today with VS 2019.

Answer (score 17):

Restarting Visual Studio with **administrator** privilege solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you are running Visual Studio as a administrator.

Comment: I was running VS as administrator. At the time I didn't know we need to install the package on each project.

Answer (score 10):

First  "Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease" and then Restarting Visual Studio as a *Administrator* worked for me together.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I tried most of the solution provided by other folks but it worked for me with below steps. I have VS 2017.

Steps:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
```

then create a class as

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext { public MyDBContext() { } }
```

and at the last execute

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

What didn't work for me:

: Restarting VS.

: only "Enable-Migrations" command, which is without -EnableAutomaticMigrations.

: restoring or updating Nuget Package Manager.

My original error in the beginning was

/*
The term 'enable-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.At line:1 char:1
+ enable-migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
*/

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem in **asp.net core** VS2019

This solved it:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCoreInstall-Package
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Don't forget to set default project in Package Manager Console to your database project in case it differs.

While executing the migrations the default project also seems to play a role. At a later step it helped to install  this to my main startup project (not the EF database project):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Comment: I don't think 8 years ago .net core exists.

Comment: @AFetter It still helps people who find this later.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2012 I had the same error. Had to uninstall NuGet (Tools > Extensions and Updates > Installed > All: NuGet Package Manager: Uninstall button). Then closed Visual Studio. Then reopened Visual Studio and reinstalled NuGet (Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online > Visual Studio Gallery: NuGet Package Manager: Download button). Then in following windows: click Install button, then click close button. Then close and reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked for me, I think its a better option than forcing an upgrade to pre-release.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this symptom for me (VS2013) is uninstalling then reinstalling the EF package with Nuget.  The difference in the csproj file changed this...

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

...into this...

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I don't fully understand why yet, but it worked at least.

Comment: I had problems with add-migration/update-database etc. I tried all number of solutions but though I'm sure I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling EF, it didn't work. Until now when it did. This is not the first time I've had problems with EF packages. :(

Answer (score 2):

In .NET Core, I was able to reach the same resolution as described in the accepted answer, by entering the following in package manager console:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Core -Pre
```

Answer (score 2):

`Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Comment: After try several solutions, your solution works well for me.

Comment: Worked for me on Visual Studio Community 2015. Thanks (All the other solutions failed on my case)

Answer (score 2):

run as administrator vs =>>  Open the project

```
-> On the Package manager Console

Enable-migration
add-migration migrationName
update-database
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that it is because of some characters in project path like [ or ]
I correct the project path and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Since I already had migrations folder, I restarted Visual Studio and ran
Update-Database -verbose 
in package manager console. That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above suggestions but nothing worked for me then I updated `Nuget Package Manager` and it worked..

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Entity framework to the current project using the below command:
   PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease
2. Add a class "MyDBContext" in the Model folder as given below:

   public class MyDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public MyDBContext()
       {
       }
   }
3. Now enable migrations for the current project with the below command:
   PM> enable-migrations

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2013, try to install the UPDATE 1(RC1) and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple projects in the solution, but I had the correct Default Project set, so I thought it should work.

In the end, I had to add the `-StartupProject MyProjectName` option to the command

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. My solution was to delete `packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3` and `Restore NuGet Packages`

I noticed that `packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3/tools/EntityFramework.psd1` was missing, so this was a likely cause. How it got removed in the first place though I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if config section "entityFramework" exists and described in your .config file

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/></configSections>

        <entityFramework>
            <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
            <providers>
                <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
            </providers>
        </entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the Entity Framework.

if it is 6.3, downgrade it to 6.2 and it should work just fine

Comment: Please elaborate on this. Why should somebody downgrade the installed library version just to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**if you create an MVC Web project You should select Authentication when creating the project . by defaults is not selected.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to 6.2 helped me.
.NET Framework version 4.6.1
Project in old format(non .NET Standard)
Visual Studio should be open with Admin rights for initial migration.
I guess EF with version above 6.2 require latest .NET Framework.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the NuGet package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" was missing

Answer (score -4):

Check if the project is open in the Solution Explorer window.

This could be the cause of your problem.