# Deleting and updating db after changing model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I'm working with the mvc 5 framework in ASP.Net on a course I'm taking at my school, but I seem to have hit a wall.

I want to go back and add a field value to my main model (Student) class, but of course that means the structure of the database has to change (getting errors when I try to run it). I was told this should be doable with the command "enable-migrations -enableautomaticmigrations" typed into the Package Manager Console, but I seem to get an error message saying it's an unknown command when I type it. Or am I supposed to do something different than using these commands?

Here is the error I'm getting when I write the aforementioned command:

```
PM> enable-migrations
```

> The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, functio n, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a pa th was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:18

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure that command is Case Sensitive. Enable-Migrations.

Comment: I've tried that (another student suggested it) but alas to no avail. :S

Comment: Look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe

Comment: The problem was that my project was located in my dropbox. For some reason my visual studio doesn't like that, moved it locally and everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my project was located in my dropbox. For some reason my visual studio doesn't like that, moved it locally and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you tried reinstalling Entity framework `Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease`. Sometimes the Prerelease version is not included. Try that.  If not try `Update-Database -Force` if you already have a database. One last way is to reopening the project after closing everything in VS.