# Which command creates my database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I pulled a clean project from GitHub, and it uses Entity Framework to model the database.
I build the project, and would like to see the database.

What commands should I run to actually create it? I thought I could run `Update-Database` but it not recognized in the *Package Manager Console*. It uses EF 6, latest version.

What am I missing?

Comment: you have to create your database, EF doesnt create it for you,

Comment: Can Visual Studio create it for me?

Comment: inside visual studio you can connect to your database server, using Server Explore, then using that connection string you can use in the EF project

Comment: first run enable-migration and then add-migration initial and after that run the update-database command it will generate database for you

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the EF commands are missing, but are accessable after a restart of Visual Studio, as [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466460/1670815).