# The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, nuget

Please help me fix this issue. Below is my project.json file.

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dotnet5.6", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [ "wwwroot", "web.config" ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

When I create a brand new project, and add the same project.json file to the project, "Add-Migration" command works perfect.

As I check on the internet, people talk about Restarting VS2015 , I have done it all and still the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the `Enable-Migrations` command before your `Add-Migration`?

Or if that doesn't work, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe) seems to suggest reinstalling Entity Framework from Nuget

Comment: I created a new project, ported all necessary files and then it worked.