# Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to install EntityFramefork on one of my solutions but `Package Manager Console` can't recognie `Enable-Migrations`.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

```
project.json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Application": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
        "Models": "1.0.0-*",
        "Newtonsoft.JsonResult": "1.0.5778.10762"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I followed these steps from different threads as well with no success:
1. Reinstalled EF with the -IncludePrerelease
2. Restarted VS with administrator privilege

[Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF Core does not have Enable-Migrations command anymore. Migrations are enabled "by default". Add new migration with Add-Migration.

Documentation about package manager commands is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)