# Remove-Migration is not working in VS 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a migration that I have not yet applied (e.g. I have not ran the "Update-Database" for that created Migration yet). I want to delete this newly un-applied migration using the "Remove-Migration" command but each time I type it in the console, it gives me this error:

```
PM> Remove-Migration
Remove-Migration : The term 'Remove-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Migration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can you please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Restarting worked for Visual Studio 2015.If Not Work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486247/5576498

Comment: `Remove-Migration` command is for EF Core. For EF6 you should manually  delete the generated migration file node from the project..

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Run the command "update-database -TargetMigration:PREVIOUS_MIGRATION -verbose" with the name of your previous migration to roll back the database
2. Remove the migration .cs file in the Migrations folder