# Is there any solution for enable-migrations Command Not foundError for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2019, entity-framework-migrations

I was following a tutorial about the asp.net-mvc . I have been stuck in enable-migrations nuget package manager

I was first haunted by the enable-migrations cmd not found error so for that purpose I followed from the following link : [Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe)

enable-migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:1
+ enable-migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValid 
   ationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migra 
   tions

I did my best to find but did not found any answer on this . Can someone please help me on this matter ?

Comment: Your question has error on Entity Framework migration, not related to ASP.NET MVC and "Nuget Package Manager" at all. Also please update your question with more detail on the version of the EF nuget used, target .NET Framework version, and use correct tags.

Comment: I did edit my Post thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable the migrations with code first, a database must exist, try and build your application, add some data to the tables, re-build the application and try again