# Enable-Migrations command causing error with Entity Framework 6.4.0

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm currently learning Entity Framework (code-first approach).

1. I have created a POCO entity
2. Created a context class that inherits from `DbContext` and it exposes `DbSet` properties for the types that I want to use to be part of the model
3. In the PowerShell command window inside Visual Studio, I tried:

   ```
   PM> enable-migrations
   ```

Running this command is throwing an error:

> The term 'enable-migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:18
>   + enable-migrations <<<<
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I don't know why this happening..

I already tried :

- Restart Visual Studio
- Install and reinstall EF
- Restarting Visual Studio with administrator privilege.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "Enable-Migrations"? Maybe it's case sensitive.

Comment: Yes @FedericoRossi but no same error is showing up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe)

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi actually I dont know why my thread was closed..!! I had read that thread and all the upvoted answer I had tried by myself but no still i am getting the same error, again and again